# Form not submiting on mobile device

Tags: forms, mobile, submit, mobile-safari, google-forms

I copied a form from Google forms and styled it on my website.  The form submits properly on my desktop (Chrome, IE, Firefox) but does not get submitted when I use a mobile device (Chrome, Safari).  What could be the problem?

Comment: How do you copy the form? from page source or what?

Comment: i copied from the start of the form "<form>" towards the end of the form "</form>"

Comment: Do you have mandatory fields and do you fill them? Your device may not show alert for empty required fields.

Comment: yes i do but i'm sure that the form is trying to submit since it still goes to my thank you page.  It's just that the results doesn't go to the responses section in my google sheet